# The background for the circle next to a tag badge has a black background in dark mode

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges, dark-mode

As the title says, the background of the circle next to a tag badge has a black background, but only in dark mode.

Example:

[image: Image of problem]

This doesn't happen in light mode:

[image]

Comment: I'm using light mode. But the gold dot not being centered bothered me so much, I had to fix it with a CSS modification. The colour fix was easy in comparison :)